# How to Read the text from images(OCR) where the font style is 7 segment font

Tags: c#, .net, ocr, image-recognition, text-recognition

I have been working on extracting text from images, specifically focusing on seven-segment fonts, using .NET. Unfortunately, my attempts with popular libraries like Tesseract, IronOcr and many more have been unsuccessful, as they seem to excel with normal English fonts.

Here's a brief overview of my tries so far:

1. Tesseract (Limited to normal English fonts, unable to recognize seven-segment characters)
2. IronOcr (Similar limitations, not suitable for seven-segment fonts)
3. Leadtools
4. pretrained models
5. custom trained models
6. some matlab and python projects from internet
7. some free OCR Api's

Despite these efforts, I'm facing challenges in accurately extracting text from images with seven-segment fonts.

*Link to Images which is to be recognised:*
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1b4S-UQbxaXZPbDfOkTiC1m0qTIt6fdb7

Additionally, I've experimented with image processing techniques, including:

Cropping and zooming to the text region.
Applying gray, black and white, and binarization filters.

Comment: Can you actually add an image link? I'd also argue that for 7 segment numbers but not limited to numbers, it might be even beneficial to not use AI based recognition at all.

Comment: _"challenges in accurately extracting text from images with seven-segment fonts"_ what is your definition of "accurately"? OCR is a probability driven business. If you expect 100% all the time then it's not for you. You may also want to improve results and support the process by applying additional knowledge.